# Parenting a rigid body: Physics problem

Tags: mesh, game-engine, parent

I made a car using the [Vehicle Controller](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Physics/Objects/Vehicle) (demo file at the end/bottom of the page) concept.

It's a "rigid body" chassis, that attaches four "no collision" wheels at run-time. It works pretty good, except for this :

I modeled a "car body" and parented it to the chassis, but no matter what settings (mass/radius/form factor) I try (for both the chassis and the body) I cannot seem to make the car body a "rigid body" (or anything else than "no collision") : When I press "p" my car flies frantically up like a balloon...?

[image]

- Exactly what is the force that makes my car fly up like this ?
- The child's mass, radius and form factor values should generally be smaller than those of the parent's, right?
- Do I have to make sure the parent and the child don't intersect?
- Are there other variables that I should look for?

Comment: I can't answer how to fix, but what makes it fly away are the two physics properties fighting for priority. one wants to fall, and another wants to ... do something else. you didn't specify.

Comment: But... What would not want to fall? The chassis wants to fall (rigid body mass 10.000) but the body car should "want" to fall too, being of the same nature and slightly inferior mass..?

Comment: It's just a thing that happens. Their courses could be off by a few decimals of a millimeter and they would explode. Honestly I've been waiting for this question a Looooong time. thanks!

Comment: Well, I ended up joining `Ctrl-J` the chassis and the body. That worked good enough for the level of detail I'm aiming for.

Comment: Yeah, but it creates problems if you're trying to get bounding boxes to be happy with their children. See [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/collision-bounds-mask-not-working) question if you didn't understand that sentence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a generic rigid body joint constraint -> 6dof and lock all the values to 0

Also, you are going to want to check linked collision (so it won't collide with the chassis)

one thing to note, rigid body joints are broken in 2.73a if you delete any item, it remove ALL rigid body joints in the scene...